# How can I automate extraction of a CAB from an executable on windows?

Tags: windows, cab

On *nix boxes, cabextract can do the trick. Is my only option on windows to install cygwin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Expand.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722332%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Expand.exe does not come with Windows Vista or Win7, but http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722159(WS.10).aspx points out that it must be part of the Windows OPK or AIK.